# How to execute multiple functions from object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to call all functions that are located within object.

```
const data = {
  fruits: funcA(),
  vegetables: funcB(),
  bread: funcC(), 
}
```

Result I want to get is:

```
firstFunc();
dispatch(funcA());
dispatch(funcB());
dispatch(funcC());
someMoreFunctions();
```

My code is:

```
firstFunc();
// I need to somehow execute here all functions from object just like in example above
someMoreFunctions();
```

I realised it's worth mentioning that I want to pass those functions to child component that will execute them once clicked on:

```
<Component onClick={()=>{
  firstFunc();
    // I need to somehow execute here all functions from object just like in example above
    someMoreFunctions();
}}
```

Comment: Assuming, that data has only functions as properties, you could iterate through the object's properties and call each function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through each value of the object, and, if it is a function, call it:

```js
const data = {
  fruits: () => console.log('some fruits'),
  vegetables: function B() { console.log('more vegetables') },
  bread: (function () { return () => console.log('less bread') })(),
  pasta: 'No'
}

Object.values(data).forEach(v => typeof(v) == 'function' ? v() : null)
```

Comment: I edited question. Difficulty here is that I don't want to execute them right away, but rather once child component is clicked.

Comment: Can't you pass `data` to the onClick function and then iterate it? Or perhaps assign `const fn = () => Object.values(data).forEach(v => typeof(v) == 'function' ? v() : null)` and call `fn()` in the handler?

Answer (score -1):

Defining the function:

```js
const object = {
  function: () => console.log("You can use functions like this!"),
  anotherFunction: log()
}

function log (){
  console.log("Yet another way of doing this ");
}
```

Calling the Function:

```js
object.function;
object.anotherFunction;
```

**Remember that when calling the function you shouldn't use the parenthesis**

Comment: Your statement is exactly wrong. When calling the function you _**must**_ use the parenthesis. When assigning a function or passing a function as a parameter you do **not** use the parenthesis. `var result = object.function();` vs `var aFunc = object.function;` or `anotherFunc(object.function);`